# Adding objects to an object array and then printing out the objects from the array

Tags: java, arrays, object

This is basically a program that adds or tries to add patients details to an object array. The patients are created in the hospital constructor.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Hospital {

public static String firstName;
public static String lastName;
public static int patientID = 1;
public static int phoneNum;
private static int i = 0;
private static Hospital[] hosArray = new Hospital[100];

public Hospital(){
    firstName = "";
    lastName = "";
    patientID = 0;
    phoneNum = 0;
}

public Hospital (String fName, String lName, int pID, int pNum){
    firstName = fName;
    lastName = lName;
    patientID = patientID++;
    phoneNum = pNum; 
}

public static void scanner(){
```

The user is prompted to add stuff like first name, last name, phone number.

```
    Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter 1 to add patient: ");
    int input = user.nextInt();

    if (input == 1){
    System.out.print("Enter first name: ");
    String fName = user.next();

    System.out.print("Enter last name: ");
    String lName = user.next();

    System.out.print("Enter phone number: ");
    int pNum = user.nextInt();
```

This is where I try and add each new object to the array and it seems to work. When I add one patient
to the array it prints out that patient. However when I try and add more than one patient to the
array then the last patient I enter is printed out the same number of times as the number of patients
I tried to enter. :?

```
    if(hosArray[i] == null){
    hosArray[i] = new Hospital();
    hosArray[i] = new Hospital(fName, lName, Hospital.patientID, pNum);
    i++;
    }
    scanner();
    }
}

public int getpID(){
    return patientID;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    scanner();

    for (int j = 0; j < hosArray.length; j++){
        if (hosArray[j] != null )
        {
            System.out.println(hosArray[j].firstName);
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is the output of my program.

```
Enter 1 to add patient: 1
Enter first name: joe
Enter last name: bloggs
Enter phone number: 1234
Enter 1 to add patient: 1
Enter first name: john
Enter last name: doe
Enter phone number: 4321
Enter 1 to add patient: 0
john
john
```

For the life of me I can't understand why its not printing out the array and I would appreciate any
help with this that I can get. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have firstName and lastName patientID and phoneNumber defined as static variables.  Every time you add a new object you are setting the those variables but all other objects of that class share the variables because they are static.  Only the last patient you enter in will show up for all print outs because static variables are shared by all objects of that class.

I fixed your code so it will do what you are trying to do but there are still somethings wrong with the code.  For one all patients will have same id = 1.

```
public class Hospital {

    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public static int patientID = 1;
    public int phoneNum;
    private static int i = 0;
    private static Hospital[] hosArray = new Hospital[100];

    public Hospital() {
        firstName = "";
        lastName = "";
        patientID = 0;
        phoneNum = 0;
    }

    public Hospital(String fName, String lName, int pID, int pNum) {
        firstName = fName;
        lastName = lName;
        patientID = patientID++;
        phoneNum = pNum;
    }

    public static void scanner() {
        Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter 1 to add patient: ");
        int input = user.nextInt();

        if (input == 1) {
            System.out.print("Enter first name: ");
            String fName = user.next();

            System.out.print("Enter last name: ");
            String lName = user.next();

            System.out.print("Enter phone number: ");
            int pNum = user.nextInt();
            if (hosArray[i] == null) {
                hosArray[i] = new Hospital();
                hosArray[i] = new Hospital(fName, lName, Hospital.patientID,
                        pNum);
                i++;
            }
            scanner();
        }
    }

    public int getpID() {
        return patientID;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        scanner();

        for (int j = 0; j < hosArray.length; j++) {
            if (hosArray[j] != null) {
                System.out.println(hosArray[j].firstName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using static variables in the Hospital class. These variables are shared across all Hospital objects, so when you update for example, the name, all Hospital objects will have that same name. Remove static from the properties that are unique to each Hospital object, like name, patiendID etc.